# Slurm environment variable for requested time

Tags: slurm

For a slurm job, the environment variable `$SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES` gives the number of nodes requested.

Is there a similar variable that gives the run time requested? I couldn't find the answer and I have tried `$SLURM_JOB_TIME`, `$SLURM_TIME` and `$SLURM_SUBMIT_TIME`, but none of these works.

Ultimate goal is to let the script I run know how much time is given to run, see an example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=abc
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --job-name=xyz
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=1

python my_python_script.py --run_time $SLURM_JOB_TIME --run_nodes $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variables that are set in Slurm jobs are called *output environment variables* ; they are listed in the [sbatch manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#SECTION_OUTPUT-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES).

No such variable exists for the time requested.

Within the submission script, you can query the Slurm controller for the information with `squeue`. Your script could look like

```
TIME=$(squeue -j $SLURM_JOB_ID -h --Format TimeLimit)
python my_python_script.py --run_time $TIME --run_nodes $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary remark, even if the accepted solution works perfectly fine, one can do in the slurm launcher:

```bash
export grepScontrol=$(scontrol show job $SLURM_JOB_ID | grep "TimeLimit")
job_time_limit=$(echo ${grepScontrol} | awk -F'[ =]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="TimeLimit") print $(i+1)}')
```

Inside python, you can access the environment variable like so:

```py
import os
time_limit = os.environ.get('time_limit')
hours, minutes, seconds = [int(part) for part in duration_str.split(":")]
```